# handling list in jsp

Tags: list, jsp, struts2

I am getting a list in my jsp page as below:

```
<s:iterator value="myList"> 
    <td><s:property value="id" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="col1" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="col2" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="col3"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="checkboxFlag" /></td>
</s:iterator>
```

Now, based on the value of checkboxFlag in above list, I want to populate a checkbox. If the value is Y, checkbox should be checked else not.

How can I achieve this ?

Below code is not working:

```
<s:iterator value="taskList">   
    <td><s:property value="id" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="col1" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="col2" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="col3"/></td>
    <td><s:checkbox name="status" <%if ("checkboxFlag".equals("Y")){ %> 
        checked="checked" <%} %>
    ></s:checkbox></td>    </s:iterator>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: If you ask a question about struts2, you'd better tag it with the struts2 tag.

Comment: what is `status` on <%if ... %>, and where is your flag on the second code block

Comment: @Jaiwo99: sorry.. status is checkboxFlag property of the tasklist on which I want to decide the condition of the checkbox

Comment: Have you tried the code from @JBNizet , it is the right answer, or you have problem with that?

Comment: @Jaiwo99: I tried and it works. But I want to know how. Going through documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to check it according to `checkBoxFlag` then use 
`<s:checkbox name="status" value='checkboxFlag == "Y"'/>`.

Answer (score 1):

`Scriptlet`s are not recommended in jsp for the purpose of removing business logic away from the view. I would recommend that you use `JSTL core` instead. It has the ff tag that you can use:

(Sample)

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${ param.status eq 'Y'}">
  <s:checkbox name="status" checked="checked" />
 </c:>
 <c:otherwise>
  <s:checkbox name="status" />
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```